# Advanced Permissions not editable in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, permissions, file-permissions

Windows 10 Version 1511 build 10586.164.

From a administrator's user account, when I open the properties of a folder and go to the advanced permissions, the "change permissions" button is gone; if I press the "view" button, I cannot change any permissions as they are grayed out.

Am I doing something wrong or has something changed in this build of Windows 10 from the way we use to change advanced permissions?

[image: advanced security settings]

[image: permission entry dialog]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nothing has changed, at least not since Windows 8.

The problem is that the permission entries you can't edit are inherited from the parent object.

[image: before]

Click the *Disable inheritance* button, then choose *Convert inherited permissions into explicit permissions on this object*.

[image: changing]

And now you can edit them all:

[image: after]

Clicking Edit results in a useful Permission Entry dialog:

[image: the second dialog]

I imagine this worked in other places (or for other entries on the same object) because those weren't inherited. Access control entries can only be modified when the object in question hasn't inherited it from anywhere else.

Comment: Why did they add these extra steps? I skipped migrating to W8, I still use W7 as main PC, W10 as a test PC...Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Moab I don't know; I can't actually remember a time when you didn't have to explicitly remove inheritance before editing those entries. If I had a Windows 7 or XP machine to test on, I would.

Comment: I Never had to do it in W7....

Comment: I created that test folder on the root of C:, I guess it inherited those permissions from C:?, it never does this in W7..

Comment: @Moab The owner of that folder, is different, from the owner you were attempting to change the permission with.  `DV7/User` to be percise.

Comment: It was the same for the owner also, grayed out.